# How do you get form post data to append an array also passed by the POST method?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, input

I want the user to add some values to a form and then submit using POST.  This is a page that has two buttons: add another record or save and exit.  If "add another record" is selected I want the page to add the data to an array and reload the form for further data entry.  On "save and exit" I want all the the data from the array to be added to the database.

```
<?php

$rows = $_POST['rows'];
$row = $_POST['row'];
$button = $_POST['button'];


if ($button <> "save and exit") {
echo '

<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>

for ($i=0;$i<$row;$i++) {
<tr>
<td>'.$rows[$i][name].'</td>
<td>'.$rows[$i][address].'</td>
</tr>
}

<form method="post" action = '.$page.'>
<input type="text" name="rows['.$row.'][name]">
<input type="text" name="rows['.$row.'][address]">
<input type="hidden" name="row" value ='.($row+1).'>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="add another record">
<input type="submit" name="button" value="save and exit">
</form>
';
}

if ($button == "save and exit"){
// send data from the $rows array to the DB
}

?>
```

But this does not work! Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take look at this. Its working

```
<?php 
    if($_POST['button']=='add another record')
    {
        for($i=0;$i<=$_POST['row'];$i++)
        {
         $rows .= "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='rows[".$i."][name]' value='".$_POST['rows'][$i]['name']."'>".$_POST['rows'][$i]['name']."</td>";
         $rows .= "<td><input type='hidden' name='rows[".$i."][address]' value='".$_POST['rows'][$i]['address']."'>".$_POST['rows'][$i]['address']."</td></tr>";

        }
    }
    else
    {
        $row = 0;
        $rows='';
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action = ''>
        <table><?php echo $rows; ?></table>
    <input type="text" name="rows[<?php if(isset($_POST['row'])) { echo ++$_POST['row']; } else { echo "0"; }; ?>][name]">
    <input type="text" name="rows[<?php if(isset($_POST['row'])) { echo ++$_POST['row']; } else { echo "0"; }; ?>][address]">
    <input type="hidden" name="row" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['row'])) { echo ++$_POST['row']; } else { echo "0"; }; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="add another record">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="save and exit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing ..
as you set the form on base of post method. just do

```
if ($button == "add another record" && count($_POST['row']) > 0) {
echo '<input type="text" name="rows[name]['.$row.']">
      <input type="text" name="rows[address]['.$row.']">';
      <input type="hidden" name="row[$row+1]" value ='.$row+1.'>
}
```

Comment: I just edited the code to account for the error you have picked up.  Still not working.